# How to create Live CD once I downloaded the zip file.

Tags: live-cd

I am trying to use Ubuntu to recover my Windows XP password on an old computer.

I have the zip files and WinZip but how do I create an ISO image on a DVD?

I have Ubuntu 12.04.2 and 12.10 desktop

Comment: Where did you get Ubuntu from (it does not usually come in a ZIP compressed file)?

Comment: for what you want to do, I suggest using Ultimate boot CD. It has the tools you need to fix XP.  http://www.ubcd4win.com/

Answer (score 2):

First download the Ubuntu ISO file from the Ubuntu website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

If you're running Ubuntu on the PC your making the CD with then use Brasero Disc Burner(which I think is included).

If you're running Windows 7 then you can use W7's built-in ISO burner. If running XP then you can get [**Infra Recorder**](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/infrarecorder_portable).

Keep in mind that these all require you have a CD-RW or DVD-RW drive in your PC.

Also if you just want to access password protected accounts on Windows XP then you can just use **[Kon-Boot](http://piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/index2.html#free)** to bypass the password checks.

If you really want to actually recover the passwords you'll need to use a tool like **[Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/)** to actually brute force guess the password(which takes a long time).

If you wish to just change the passwords you can use **[Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)**. **(WARNING: Using this method could lock you out of Protected Folders that use the account's password!)**

Comment: When i burned the file it burned as a WINZIP chunk. What I am trying to do is get into my windows xp account but I forgot the password. Booting xp from old HD. Can't get to command line. Ubutu downloads not working the way I expect. There are other tools recommended here. Assume I can trust them all.

Comment: @tom All the tools I've mentioned can be trusted. Make sure you download the ISO file and burn that using one of the Burning tools I mentioned, since I know those work. Some of the tools are provided in ZIP files that contain the ISOs.